# Best way to track the progress of a long-running function (from outside) - PostgreSQL 11?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

What is the best way to track progress of a
long-running function in PostgreSQL 11?

Since every function executes in a single transaction, even if the function writes to some "log" table no other session/transaction can see this output unless the function completes with SUCCESS.

I read about some attempts here but they are from 2010.

https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2010/04/viewing-postgres-function-progress-from/

Also, this approach looks terribly inconvenient.

As of today what is the best way to track progress?

One approach that I know... is to turn the func to a procedure and then do partial commits in the SP. But what if I want to return some result set from the func... In that case I cannot turn it into a SP, right? So... how to proceed in that case?

Many thanks in advance.

**NOTE: The function is written in PL/pgSQL, the most common procedural SQL language available in PostgreSQL.**

Comment: What language is the function written in? Depending on what you are using there might be more / less facilities available

Comment: I think @Jeremy is right. For the times that I've looked into this, it seems like the only options are kludgy and not really something that most people would be OK with rolling into production. I wish this could be added as a feature.

Comment: The function is written in PL/pgSQL, the most common procedural SQL lang available in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Note that the blog post mentioned in the original question has moved to: https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2010/04/viewing-postgres-function-progress-from/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that there's a great way to do it built-in to postgres yet, but there are a couple ways to achieve logging that will be visible outside of a function.

1. You can use the pg_background extension to run an insert in the background that will be visible outside of the function.  This requires compiling and installing this extension.
2. Use dblink to connect to the same database and insert data.  This will most likely require setting up some permissions.

Neither option is ideal, but hopefully one can work for you. Converting your function to a procedure may also work, but you won't be able to call the procedure from within a transaction.

Comment: I typically sprinkle the function with `RAISE NOTICE` and run it from `psql`.